# How can I force vertical text to be horizontal?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internationalization

I'm working on an ASP.NET website that needs to be internationalized. I'm using .resx files (essentially key-value pairs in a file) to populate static string fields on a page in different languages depending on the chosen culture/locale.  I'm implementing Japanese and getting some stubborn vertical strings.

When copy and pasting them into the .resx file, they are horizontal (source of strings is Google Translate, for testing purposes).  All of the strings appear normal, but one always displays vertically.  The misbehaving string is a few div's deep (like all of them) and only has font-size, font-family, color, and an uppercase transform applied to it.

Removing any or all of the above rules does not change the orientation of the text.  I've cleaned the formatting off the offending text with Notepad and shortened it (to ensure it wasn't a length problem).  I'm stumped as to why this particular string is stubbornly vertical.

Here is the text in question: ログアウト
(Translation: Logout)

**Edit**

Clarification of the issue.

What it should look like: 
[image: What it should look like]

The vertical text in question:
[image: The vertical text in question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I force vertical text to be
>   horizontal?

Other than the title, I don't really understand your question. I'll take a guess anyway.

Try adding [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) to the `div` that's misbehaving.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was doing some learning about right-to-left on the web and learned that [Unicode characters have a directional property associated with them at the character level](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/#typing). So this might have something to do with that, though I certanily wouldn't know how to ascertain that or fix it, especially given that Google Translate is the source of the strings.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know that about Unicode, but I tried their suggested solution and no luck.

Comment: What is the rendered width of the text's parent element when you inspect it in Firebug or WebInspector?

Comment: The whitespace solution is correct, but for reference: the rendered width was 9x73.

Comment: Interesting. Without the white-space:nowrap declaration, I wonder if the text would have still rendered vertically if you'd forced its width to 100% or some other fixed pixel value.

Comment: I tried setting width to 100% and a fixed pixel value.  Setting it to a fixed pixel value works, but is not optimal as different languages will need different widths and if it's too wide it gives the text an odd offset.

Answer (score 0):

It happens quite often for Asian scripts (not just Japanese but also Korean and Chinese) to have text rendered incorrectly. Usually you just need to play with element width, especially if it is part of HTML table.